# I am unable to access the ./demoCA/newcerts directory ./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, windows, openssl, x509certificate

I am working on sample application for creating server/client certificate pair using OpenSSL in node js.

[I used the following commands from this link](http://manmoahn-openssl-net.blogspot.in/2011/07/creating-serverclient-certificate-pair.html)
I have created the CA successfully while creating server the following error occured.

> I am unable to access the ./demoCA/newcerts directory ./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory

I have not not created any directory named demoCA. Is

> ./demoCA/newcerts

is the default directory or I need to create it. Explain how to create server and client certificate using CA.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).